# Expo Speech Rate Documentation

Tags: expo, documentation, speech-to-text

Android and IoS use a different type for the rate value in Expo Text to Speech API.

The documentation says that the rate is a text but when I use text for the rate, I get an error on Android and not on IoS saying that it is a number. Here is the code that works.

```
  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    Speech.speak(textData, {
      onDone: () => Speech.stop(textData),
      voice: "en-gb-x-gbb-network",
      rate: 0.8,
    });
  } else {
    Speech.speak(textData, {
      onDone: () => Speech.stop(textData),
      voice: "com.apple.ttsbundle.siri_Gordon_en-AU_compact", 
      rate: "0.83",
    });
  }/*
```

My question is - how can I let expo know that their documentation is wrong and let others know.